# Accurate map of Ceres

Tags: reference-request, mapping, ceres

What is the most accurate, publically available map we have of Ceres, including official names of all named craters? Any data sets on Cerean geography would be very welcome.

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/@37.5928645,-120.956808,14.63z seems simple. Don't see any craters though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [USGS Astrogeology Science Center's Astropedia](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search?pmi-target=ceres) is an excellent source for derived mapping data products (though only 7 Ceres products).

Here is a ["Ceres Nomenclature"](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Ceres/Nomenclature/ceres) data product:
[image]

Comment: Is this it though? There are lots of unnamed craters visible in these images, are they really unnamed or just not shown here?

Comment: @Innovine There is also [Ceres Dawn Zeilnhofer Crater Database 2020](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Ceres/Dawn/Craters/ceres_dawn_fc2_craterdatabase_zeilnhofer_2020) available on Astropedia. It has ~45,000 crater identified of which only 117 are named.

Comment: Does that mean they are unnamed, or just unnamed in astropedias data?

Comment: @Innovine it means they are (almost certainly) unnamed

Answer (score 13):

NASA has produced a [topographical features map of Ceres](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/jpl/pia19974/topographic-ceres-map-with-feature-names-ii), with names for some craters. The map was produced in 2015.

[image]

[This one](https://planetary.s3.amazonaws.com/web/assets/pictures/20160929_Ceres-map_lg.jpg) has few more details,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jmars software to see the geography of ceres and other planetary bodies https://jmars.mars.asu.edu/